# What is a Motley Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Motley Word™**.  Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Motley Word™ | Not Motley Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| mesmerize | dazzle |
| beacon | incandescence |
| pigment | dye |
| glow | gleam |
| radiance | luster |
| gloss | shine |
| tincture | effulgence |
| resplendency | sumptuousness |
| woven | netted |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Motley Word™, Not Motley Word™
mesmerize, dazzle
beacon, incandescence
pigment, dye
glow, gleam
radiance, luster
gloss, shine
tincture, effulgence
resplendency, sumptuousness
woven, netted
```

---

**Hint 1:**

> [image: description]

**Hint 2:**
<sub>Note: This hint may give the solution away.  I suggest trying to solve it with only the first hint.</sub>

> [image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the definion of Motley:

> "made up of a variety of colours" or "
>  the multicoloured costume of a jester"

And:

> Being {**R**,**O**,**Y**,**G**,**B**,**I**,**V**} the initial of the name of the colours in the visible spectrum, A Motley word is that one which contains 2 or more of these letters (one letter is not "multicolour"):

Proof:

> Motley Words™:
>  - mesme**RI**ze
>  - **B**eac**O**n
>  - p**IG**ment
>  - **G**l**O**w
>  - **R**ad**I**ance
>  - **G**l**O**ss
>  - **I**nctu**R**e
>  - **R**esplendenc**Y**
>  - w**OV**en
>
>  Not Motley Words™:
>  - dazzle
>  - **I**ncandescence
>  - d**Y**e
>  - **G**leam
>  - luste**R**
>  - sh**I**ne
>  - efful**G**ence
>  - sumptu**O**usness
>  - netted